# Grub last update (17/11) problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates, grub-efi

After the latest Ubuntu, so Grub update, my computer has problems to open immediately Grub for choosing the OS.

Appear an error message saying:

```
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi Not Found
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft/Boot\MokManager.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\MokManager.efi Not Found
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi Not Found
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi Not Found
Checking media [Fail]
```

After checking media again another couple of times, it open Grub.

I tried BootRepair and to reinstall, but it didn't change anything. During the update appeared a menu about where Grub should be installed or some similar setting I can't remember, I just choose the recommended option.

info about all my boot settings here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13326048/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is this:

1. The computer is trying to boot from `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the ESP. Instead of being Windows (as this file should be), it's a copy of Shim, which then tries to launch, in turn, `grubx64.efi` and `MokManager.efi` from the same directory. Both of these files are missing, so this step displays error messages, fails, and leads to....
2. The computer tries to boot from `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, which is also Shim, which tries to launch the same follow-on programs from that directory. These files are absent, so....
3. The computer boots `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`. This copy of Shim succeeds in launching `grubx64.efi` and the boot process succeeds normally.

Tracking backward in time, Boot Repair will sometimes set up copies of GRUB (and Shim and related tools) in `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` and in `EFI/BOOT` as a way of working around ugly EFI bugs that prevent some computers from remembering their boot orders. This Boot Repair practice is an ugly hack that is a workaround for an equally ugly bug. Sometimes it's necessary, but there are also cases when it's applied unnecessarily. Over-application of this copying hack was particularly common a few years ago, but the Boot Repair developers eventually stepped back and made such copying an option rather than the default.

In any event, it looks like this Boot Repair hack was applied to your system and then something (the GRUB update, perhaps) went in and deleted `grubx64.efi` and `MokManager.efi` from the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` and `EFI/BOOT` directories on your ESP. This would result in precisely the behavior you see. This hypothesis is somewhat supported by the `efibootmgr` output in your Boot Repair output (lines 1002-1010), which shows a boot order of the Microsoft boot manager followed by Ubuntu. (There's no evidence of a boot to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` in there, but that could be the action of the EFI bug that Boot Repair's hack is intended to overcome.)

***BEWARE:*** You're treading in dangerous territory because your system is in a non-standard state and, if Boot Repair's hack was necessary, your firmware is defective. Attempts to fix this problem, if unsuccessful, could create even worse problems. Before you do anything else, I strongly recommend that you back up your ESP (`/boot/efi` in Ubuntu). That will provide some recovery options if things get worse.

It's possible that the following command will fix the problem:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0001,0002,0003,2001
```

In theory, that at least should not make matters any worse; but if your computer really required the ugly hack of a workaround applied by Boot Repair, all bets are off. If your firmware is defective, this command may end up having no effect at all, in which case another solution may be necessary: Copy `grubx64.efi`, `grub.cfg`, and `MokManager.efi` from `EFI/ubuntu` on the ESP (`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` in Linux) to `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` and to `EFI/BOOT` on the ESP.

If copying the files is necessary, then your firmware is defective, and a better solution is to replace your defective computer with one that works. This may sound like an over-reaction, but certain manufacturers (HP and Sony spring to mind) have been delivering defective EFIs for years. Call me frustrated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very useful... I solved with the 2nd option, copying the files... Actually I'm having problems with boot/EFI since I have this computer, it can be a firmware problem... Not this time, but usually the problems came after going in the Win7 partition, so I was thinking was Win to mess up the boot manager. Do you think should I risk to do an BIOS update? I saw one which looks to be more recent then the one I have, but there are no info about which bugs are fixed....

Comment: Updating your firmware may be worth doing. There's a very small risk of "bricking" a computer when doing such an update, so I wouldn't do it without cause -- but if you're having problems getting your boot order to "stick," then that's sufficient cause to risk an update.